# How to handle a growing React view controller component

Tags: reactjs

I have a React view controller component with lots of functions that do lots of cool stuff, but it's growing pretty large.  I have already broken down all presentation components to their own files.  I usually like to keep my files short (around 500 lines or less) and this one is a little over 700 lines, so it's not crazy big but I think it could get out of hand soon.  My question is:

What are some possible ways to handle trimming the size of a view controller with lots of functions?  Has anyone else hit this issue?

Comment: My concept of 'short files' is under 100 lines. Up to 200 lines, I'd consider 'ok'. When it gets to 200 lines I start to think of ways to break things in smaller parts. I imagine you're using React without any Flux implementation, right? (then keeping most of your logic on a top component and passing them down as props, which is ok). If that's true, I think you should try using Flux or one of its implementations. With Redux, for example, you'd be able to push a lot of your logic to actions/reducers.

Comment: @rafaelbiten thanks for the helpful response.  I am using a Flux implementation with actions and I've thought about moving all of the functions into the actions, but then what I would get is something like:
function1() {
  action1()
}
function2() {
  action2()
}
function3() {
  action3()
}
I think what I need is a way to dispatch the actions efficiently.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I don't know why you'd need the extra wrapping functions.. can't you just dispatch actions where they occur? Might be beneficial to post some code so we can make more specific proposals

Comment: I would rather not allow the action to be dispatched at the source of the event.  I want to keep the components either smart or dumb and send events from the dumb component up to the view controller.  Only the view controller can access the dispatcher or store.
`Component {
  doSomething1(){
    // dispatch something1
  }
  doSomething2(){
    // dispatch something2
  }
  doSomething3(){
    // dispatch something3
  }
  doSomething4(){
    // dispatch something4
  }
  doSomething5(){
    // dispatch something5
  }
  doSomething6(){
    // dispatch something6
  }
}`

Comment: So I've actually come up with a solution that works for me.  I've moved all non-lifecycle methods to a new `controller.js` file which handles all data changes in the Main View Component.  
Even though this file is pretty large I think this is the horizontal scale I'm looking for.  As the `controller.js` file grows, I may create a folder called `controllers` and move all methods to their own file.  I'm pretty excited about this and think it will scale well.
Anyone else have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

thig might help you:

first, create a view like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
//  controller
import HomeController from "../../controllers/danishControler"; 


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       data: 0
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("the set value is "+this.state.data)
    return (
      <div className="App"> 

       <HomeController data={this.state.data}>
         { data=>
         <div>
            <p>{data.obj.Name}</p>
            <p>{data.obj.FatherName}</p>
            <p>{data.obj.msg}</p>
            </div>
        }
       </HomeController>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

here is the controller code, I code this using arrow function because I not need 
states

```
 // model
 import homeModal from "../models/homeModel";
 const HomeController = props => {
  const { name, fatherName, msg } = homeModal(props.data);
  console.log(name+fatherName+msg)
  return props.children({
    obj: {
      Name: name,
      FatherName: fatherName,
      msg:msg
    }
  });
};
export default HomeController;
```

and here is the model

```
var msg ,  name ,fatherName;
var returnObj;

function homeModal(props){


    console.log("value of data is " )
    switch(props) {
        case 1:
                name =   "Danish "
                fatherName ="Abdur Rehman" 
                msg="Your Data has Fetched "
                returnObj = { name, fatherName , msg} 
                break
        case 2:
                name = "Rashid Iqbal" 
                fatherName ="Muhammad Iqbal" 
                msg="Your Data has Fetched "
                returnObj = { name, fatherName , msg} 
                break
        default:
                msg = "Data Not Found"
                returnObj = {msg} 
                break
    }


    return returnObj

}

export default homeModal
```